# Can you be a postdoc with funding from a private organization (vs. government funding)?

Tags: funding, postdocs

Can you be a post-doc if you secured funding from a private organization to do research at a university in the social sciences/humanities, or do you have to have governmental funding to do a postdoc?

Comment: You could even be self-funded if you have enough money to pay your living expenses and the other costs of your research are covered in some way.

Comment: thank you for this, but I specifically asked this question and I was told a clear NO. very strange to hear that you say you can... I am starting to think, would there be a difference from one institution to another?

Comment: As [@Fomite writes](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57643/can-you-be-a-postdoc-with-funding-from-a-private-organization-vs-government-fu?noredirect=1#comment134981_57668), this might be a (strange) institution-specific rule. They might have a reason for it. I'd suggest you simply ask them why this rule exists.

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely possible to have a postdoc funded by a private organization - there's nothing about a postdoc inherently tied to a particular type of funding. A couple ways this might happen:

- As @Dexter mentions, there are private trusts and charitable organizations that fund research. This can occur either by funding a fellowship directly, or allowing funds from a grant to be used to hire a postdoc.
- There are also commercial companies that have research grant programs in a number of fields. It's entirely possible to use the funding from one of these to pay for a postdoc.
- A private university could directly pay for a postdoc - for example, as part of a professor's startup package.

Comment: Great! This makes sense, but I was told that you can only be a post doc if you get funded from a federal funding or like a Fullbright... No private company can fund you for a post doc, but you can be a visiting scholar in terms of international researchers... I am starting to dought this advice I received!

Comment: @Ree If that advice is true, it's institution-specific.

Comment: i am going to check this now!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **Yes**, you can apply for post doc position in university if you have private funding. (Example of such funding is [wellcome trust](http://www.wellcome.ac.uk/Funding/Humanities-and-social-science/index.htm) funding for Humanities and social science)

Warnings: You should *always* check norms with your funding agencies and universities because some times it is possible to have conflict of interest between both.

Comment: sounds convincing. I thought the only restriction to apply for a postdoc is that it has to be within 5 years of earning your phd. I was shocked to hear that private companies can not fund for a post doc. Again, I am seriously doubting this piece of info I was given.